# Выровнять блок по центру вертикали другого блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: brackets]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда хочу сделать отступ блоку `logo`, отступ делается внутри блока `screen`, а от него. Я знаю что можно сделать `position: absolute;` и отступ в процентах, но мне нужно в пикселях. Скажите, есть способ решить данную проблему?

Comment: Можно сделать `position: absolute` и отступ в пикселях. Сделайте не у лого `margin-top: 170px`, а у `.screen` - `padding-top: 170px`

Comment: Почему бы логотипу не дать стиль: padding-top:?

Comment: @2booos Вам помог хотя бы один ответ? Если да, то отметьте его как принятый. Если нет, то оставьте уточняющий комментарий.

Answer (score 3):

**Вариант №1:**

```
.screen {
   position: relative;
   background-color: #222;
   height: 100vh;
   padding-top: 170px;
}

.logo {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 86px;
   width: 340px;
   background: url("/img/logo.png");
}
```

**Вариант №2:**

```
.screen {
   position: relative;
   background-color: #222;
   height: 100vh;
}

.logo {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding-top: 170px;
   height: 86px;
   width: 340px;
   background-image: url("/img/logo.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 0;
   background-position-y: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, извините что код был скрином, и вам пришлось переписывать

Comment: @2booos, та ладно, уже привык. Код за одну минуту переписал )

Comment: а не подскажите, как сделать что бы logo с изминением размера экрана тоже подстраивался(как в бутстрапе class image-responsive)

Comment: @2booos, для этого используйте свойства @media: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#wikiArticle . Там можно указывать два параметра или больше: `@media (max-width: 250px) and (min-width: 100px)`

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Решение через Flexbox

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  display: flex;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Решение через псевдоэлемент с поддержкой IE 9

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Обертка */
.container-fluid:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Блок, который нужно выровнять */
.row {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 3. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

#### 4. Решение через line-height

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```