# Как вертикально отцентрировать блок в контейнере?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, позиционирование

Как строку `.row` поставить в центр `.container-fluid` (вертикально отцентрировать)?

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выровнять блок по центру вертикали другого блока](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610909/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: @Vadizar Там вопрос некачественный (код картинкой), и там я так понял, вопрос больше про отступы, чем просто центрирование.

Comment: Вам дали несколько ответов. Если вам подошёл какой-либо, то отметьте его как принятый. Если нет — оставьте уточняющий комментарий, чем именно вам не подходят данные ответы. Также можете голосовать за полезные ответы.

Comment: Поставил минус данному вопросу, т.к. автору были даны ответы, он ничего не выбрал и никак не комментирует это.

Answer (score 5):

Проще всего это сделать через flexbox.

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  display: flex;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не сработает в IE 9. А IE 10 и 11 только частичная поддержка.

Comment: @Vadizar Я думаю, что можно уже спокойно не поддерживать IE9, иногда даже IE10. А для IE11 это прекрасно работает, можете проверить.

Comment: @Vadizar Вы так заботитесь о поддержке старых браузеров, как будто это самое главное в веб-разработке. Кому надо, пусть даже IE6 поддерживает и ищет нужные устаревшие способы.

Comment: @Vadizar Кстати использовать polyfill для старых браузеров — тоже адекватное решение. Поэтому мне кажется вы скорей любите "антиквариат", чем ориентируетесь на практическую пользу в своих решениях.

Comment: зачем использовать JS, когда можно сделать все на CSS? Тем более мой вариант можно где угодно применить. Если вы не знаете основы, то не нужно называть чужой код антиквариатом.

Comment: @Vadizar Вы "основами" называете устаревшие и в данном случае намного менее сопроводаемые способы создания разметки. Посмотрите сколько у вас кода занимает просто расположение элемента по вертикали, а также необходимость `!improtant`, что не есть хорошо. Но вы обязательно будете хвастаться "Зато в IE9 работает", который нужно сейчас поддерживать очень мало кому.

Answer (score 1):

Если это будет единственная кнопка, можно сделать её абсолютной:

```
position:absolute;
top:calc(50% - 200px);
left:calc(50% - половина_ширины);
```

И для родителя дать:

```
position:relative;
```

Иначе - можно использовать `flexbox`, если Вам не важен IE.

Answer (score 0):

Если известна высота родительского элемента(как в вашем примере), то просто:

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Или так:

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

#### 1. Решение через Flexbox

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  display: flex;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Решение через псевдоэлемент с поддержкой IE 9

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Обертка */
.container-fluid:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Блок, который нужно выровнять */
.row {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 3. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

#### 4. Решение через line-height

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```